# Randomly selecting rows from a dataframe based on a column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas data frame as follows:

```
col1, col2, label
a    b      0
b    b ,    0
.
.
..........  0
..........  1
```

and the `value_counts` for the label column:

```
df['label'].value_counts():

0: 200000
1: 10000
```

I want to select 50000 rows from label with value '0' at random such that my value_counts become:

```
0: 50000
1: 10000
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Filter each value and [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) `N` values from each. Then, get their indexes, join through `union` and just `loc`

```
s0 = df.label[df.label.eq(0)].sample(50000).index
s1 = df.label[df.label.eq(1)].sample(10000).index 

df = df.loc[s0.union(s1)]
```

---

Of course, you don't need to specify the `10000` in the `s1` if you're just getting all of them :) It's just there for illustration

Comment: This worked! I *tried to*  remove(d) :P the sampling from the second set since I am essentially just trying to retain that data as is. Thanks! And also you need to reassign the data frame to itself to keep the new dataframe or store it to a new variable if you want to preserve the original dataframe.

Comment: Glad I could help ;)

Comment: will the rows be distinct upon sampling?

Comment: To answer my own question, yes it is when 'replace' is False which is the default value