# select randomly rows from a dataframe based on a column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame called `df` of which its value counts are the following:

```
df.Priority.value_counts()

P3    39506
P2    3038 
P4    1138 
P1    1117 
P5    252  
Name: Priority, dtype: int64
```

I am trying to create a balanced dataset called `df_balanced` from `df` by restricting the number of entries in the `P3` category to 5000. The expected output should look like this!

```
P3    5000
P2    3038 
P4    1138 
P1    1117 
P5    252  
Name: Priority, dtype: int64
```

I tried the following code:

```py
s0 = df.Priority[df.Priority.eq('P3')].sample(5000).index

df_balanced = df.loc[s0.union(df)].reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)  # I am unsure how to exclude the entries of `P3` categories from `df`!
```

I used this as a reference: [Randomly selecting rows from a dataframe based on a column value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57405126/10543310) but the solution provided isn't optimal for more than 2 categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Filter bug reports with priority P3 and sample 5000 rows from it

`df_sampleP3 = df[df['Priority'] == 'P3'].sample(n=5000, random_state=123)`

2. Create a separate dataframe containing all other bug reports

`df_sampleRest = df[df['Priority'] != 'P3']`

3. Concatenate the two dataframes to create the new balanced bug reports dataset

`df_balanced = pd.concat([df_sampleRest, df_sampleP3])`

`print(f"Shape = {df_balanced.shape}\n")`

4. Check the status of the class imbalance

`df_balanced.Priority.value_counts()`

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```
import random

# this is the maximum limit of elements of P1, which will be
# randomly chosen
maxlim_catP1 = 4

df.groupby('X').apply(
    lambda g: g.loc[random.sample(g.index.to_list(), min(maxlim_catP1, len(g))), :] if
    (g.loc[g.index[0], 'X'] == 'P1') else g)
```

Output:

```
       X  Y
X          
P1 2  P1  c
   3  P1  d
   0  P1  a
   1  P1  b
P2 4  P2  e
   6  P2  g
   7  P2  h
```

Data:

```
    X  Y
0  P1  a
1  P1  b
2  P1  c
3  P1  d
4  P2  e
5  P1  f
6  P2  g
7  P2  h
8  P1  i
```